# How to find a factor of $\zeta - 1$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ for $\zeta := e^{2 \pi i / 5}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

> Let $\zeta := e^{2 \pi i / 5}$. Given that $\zeta - 1$ is a factor of $\zeta + 4$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$, find another factor of $\zeta + 4$.
>
> Remark: This is part of exercise 7 in chapter 3 of Stewart's & Tall's Algebraic Number Theory.

Unfortunately I do not see how to solve this aside frome mere guessing; which was unsuccessfull so far. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: $\zeta + 4 = \zeta -1 + 5$. Can you write $5$ as a multiple of $\zeta -1$?

Comment: E.g., by partially expanding $\frac{((\zeta -1) + 1)^5 -1}{\zeta-1} =0 $